# Не удаляются действия (хуки) в классе, добавленные через add_action

Tags: php, wordpress

В теме вордпресс используется класс, в конструкторе которого настраиваются хуки `add_action,remove_action`.
Эти хуки в классе настраиваются как-то так:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', array( $this, 'wrapper_start' ), 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', array( $this, 'wrapper_end' ), 10 );
add_filter('single_product_archive_thumbnail_size', array( $this, 'modify_product_thumbnail_size') );
```

пытаюсь переопределить так:

```
function theme_change_actions() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'Theme_WooCommerce', 'add_next_prev_product_to_single' ), 4);
}
add_action( 'init', 'theme_change_actions' );
```

но ничего не срабатывает. `Theme_WooCommerce` это имя класса, о котором идёт речь.
Можно ли как-то переопределить эти хуки в дочерней теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подключаете метод класса, а отключаете статический метод. Обычный метод относится к объекту, а статический к классу.

Чтобы удалить хук, который привязан к объекту используйте эту ф-цию отсюда https://gist.github.com/tripflex/c6518efc1753cf2392559866b4bd1a53

Пример:

```
remove_class_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'Theme_WooCommerce', 'add_next_prev_product_to_single' ), 4);
```

Comment: не затруднит подсказать, а как сделать обратное действие? т.е. как добавить хук, который привязан к объекту?

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( 'Theme_WooCommerce', 'add_next_prev_product_to_single' ));

Comment: выдаёт ошибку, Non-static method should not be called statically